# Does anyone have a fix for FireFox locking up with the new Outlook email website?

Tags: firefox, microsoft-outlook

I am using the latest version of the Firefox portable app off a flash drive. About a week ago MS Outlook changed their Outlook email website. Now, when I log in, most of the page contents loads and then the page freezes.

I am wondering if it had something to do with the ads on the right side of the page. They don't seem to load.

The MS Outlook web page works with IE. So, I am guessing that this lock up has something to do with FireFox not handling something that MS added/changed.

Version 39.0.3 of portable FireFox.

Comment: Have you tried disabling firefox addons or checked in safe mode for firefox ? Try reset it

Comment: You might add a screenshot of the login screen when it freezes. Also add the FF version number (for reference when it changes in the future). "latest" does not help since FF updated again today.